# How to have "if" statements read lists

Tags: python

Today I ran into a error, where my if statement is not reading my input, from my list. I am not sure if this is a basic error in formatting the list, or if I am writing it completely wrong.

```
def menu():

    print("================================")
    print("Welcome to rock/paper/scissors !")
    print("================================")
    
    time.sleep(1)
    
    print("Choose a play!")
    print("")
    print(" ROCK ")
    print("")
    print(" PAPER ")
    print("")
    print(" SCISSORS ")
    print("")

def main():
    
    answers = ["ROCK","Rock","rock","PAPER","Paper","paper","SCISSORS","Scissors","scissors"]
    
    for i in range(2):
        if i == 1:
            continue
        menu()

    question1 = input("Pick your choice!")
    if question1 == answers[1]:
        print("working")
    else:
        exit()
    
main()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `answers[1]` is `Rock`, and if you type in `Rock` it prints "working". What is the error you got?

Comment: It's not clear from your code what you're trying to do. Maybe the ```lower``` method could help you: ```"RoCK".lower() == "roCk".lower()```

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by "reading input from my list". Please explain what you expect to happen that is different from what actually happens. For example, are there things you can type that should cause the `if` statement to be satisfied, but don't? Are there things you can type that should cause the `if` statement *not* to be satisfied, but do?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use `.lower()` so you don't need to type out all the variations on 'Rock', 'Paper' and 'Scissors'.

Secondly, please explain this code:

```py
for i in range(2):
    if i == 1:
        continue
    menu()
```

Can't you just use `menu()`?

So the `main` function should be this:

```py
def main():
    menu()
    userinput = input('Pick: ').lower()
    if userinput == 'rock':
        '''The user picked rock - do something...'''
    elif userinput == 'paper':
        '''The user picked paper - do something...'''
    elif userinput == 'scissors':
        '''The user picked scissors - do something...'''
    else:
        '''The user didn't pick anything - do something...'''
```

Comment: Regarding. ```for i in range(2):
    if i == 1:
        continue
    menu() ```
I put that in, to stop a infinite loop of menus. (not sure if there is an easier way)

I could do the if statements, with a direct word, but I thought that making a list would cut out unnecessary clutter.